# Может ли полететь верстка, из-за более старой ОС

Tags: windows, вёрстка, windows-xp

Зависит ли отображение приложения от того в на какой windows его запускать? Например, в windows xp 32bit, в windonws 7 или в windows 10? при том что браузер используется во всех случаях одинаковый.
При запуске на виртуалке в старых версиях IE верстка отображается по разному, но не нашел никаких способов этого избежать

Comment: "...браузер используется во всех случаях одинаковый" имеется ввиду только его название - IE или  одинаковый с точностью до версии? Старые версии виндовс могут не иметь тех же шрифтов что есть в 7-10 версии виндовс.

Answer (score 1):

От версии браузера. Для IE можно ставить следущий костыль, используемый в бутстрапе и не только:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<!-- или  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">-->

        <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <![endif]-->
```

+

```
<!-- HTML5 Shiv and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

В целом, определяются и оговариваются (в ТЗ) популярные браузеры и самые старые версии, на которых верстка должна отображаться приемлемо.